# Render React JS server side using .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I did the comments tutorial on http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html and got it to render server side using .net mvc.

I have an existing mvc app where I rewrote a page in react. I'm trying to render it server side using .net but I get an error when it tries to render server side.

```
Exception Details: React.Exceptions.ReactServerRenderingException: Error while rendering "TopicAnswers" to "react1": TypeError: undefined is not a function
   at React.createClass.render (Script Document [8]:80:39) ->     var answerNodes = this.props.data.map(function(answer){
   at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (Script Document [2]:7395:34)
```

Here's the code:

In my MVC view:

```
@Html.React("TopicAnswers", new
{
    initialAnswers = Model,
    url = Url.Action("TopicAnswers", new { id = ViewBag.TopicID }),
})
```

My TopicAnswers.jsx file:

```
var TopicAnswers = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    alert('inside getInitialState: ' + this.props.initialAnswers);       
    return {answers: this.props.initialAnswers};
}
```

My ReactConfig.cs file:

```
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
                .AddScript("~/Scripts/internal/eusVote/TopicAnswers.jsx");
```

**QUESTION: Why is it having a problem rendering the react file server side?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error message trying to render React jsx file server side using .net:

**"React.Exceptions.ReactServerRenderingException: Error while rendering "TopicAnswers" to "react1": TypeError: undefined is not a function"**

My problem was that in the JSX file, I still had ComponentWillMount which called the loadAnswersFromServer. This is what you need if you are rendering client side. But once you adjust your code to render server side, you need to comment out/remove the ComponentWillMount so that it doesn't try to run the loadAnswersFromServer function on the server side.

With MVC, the data should be passed from the controller to the view and referenced in the @Html.Render("Comment", new { initialData = Model }) for the initial load.

Also, don't forget to comment out/remove the React.render( ... ) line from the JSX file.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` is available only in browser window context. When rendering it on a server you can not call any functions that are browser related. If you are calling them, then you need to shim them so they are not failing on a server.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I edited my OP to show the error message I was getting before I tried to put in the Alert. It seems that my react file "TopicAnswers.jsx" is not being read via the @Html.React in my MVC view.